# Zoho CRM Hide Fields

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, zoho

If searched the https://help.zoho.com/portal/community site
And it seems that you can only hide some fields if you have the enterprise edition.

I'm not looking for a Security solution, I only want cleaner interface so I think the only ways is to develop a chrome extension.

I've already stared to develop it in
https://github.com/fmmribeiro/scZohoHideElements

But using a "Content Script" the extension is fired before the page is fully loaded (zoho uses some kind of async content loading)

**HOW do I execute my Content Script after the page is fully loaded?**

Ps: By now the only way to bypass this problem is to click the Chrome extension button (background script)

Comment: Based on this old [reported issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114890), "add an event listener for load that uses setTimeout to register a deferred function. This should guarantee that the deferred function will run after all onload event handlers."

Comment: How do you define "fully loaded"? Usually, there's not really such a state, e.g. if the page lazy-loads more content later. You will need to monitor for changes.

Comment: See this question for a strategy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/